# Converting a string to Date

Tags: php

I have a string in the format `Apr 27 2014` and I need to convert to a date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. Is there a easy straight forward way to accomplish that? I couldn't find anything besides write a little parser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$date = new DateTime("Apr 27 2014");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:

```
2014-04-27
```

For more information about the `DateTime` class see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: You should link him to the DateTime docs too... since he had so much trouble finding it on his own ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `strtotime()` and `date()` functions:

```
<?php

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Apr 27 2014'))."\n";
```

You can look at other examples with `strtotime()` at [php.net](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php).

**Notice:** unix timestamp is limited on `32bit systems` form `~1900` till `2038`.

Comment: But be careful. The timestamp has limits in the past and the future.

Comment: Thank you, @Henrik! Added your notice to the answer.